# Moving to next page of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, javascript-objects

I've recently been trying to loop through about 50 pages of JSON objects but find myself getting stuck after the first page (30 objects). Using the code below, I am able to log the "Total" given by each object, the information I am looking for.

```
page = 1

$.get("http://[URL]/json?Cat=1&PgNum=" + page, function(data) {
    for (i in data) {
        console.log(data[i].Total)
    }
});
```

However, I am unable to find a way of going to the next page (`page++`) once I have printed all 30 "Totals". Could anyone offer any suggestions to point me in the right direction?

I am attempting to go through all the pages until the only content on the page is a single empty object, `[]`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a recursive function.

```
function printAll(){
    printFromPage(0)
}

function printFromPage(page){
    $.get("http://[URL]/json?Cat=1&PgNum=" + page, function(data) {
        for (i in data) {
            console.log(data[i].Total)
        }
        if(data.length > 0){
            printFromPage(page + 1)
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be working for me. When I attempted to run this, the "Total"s from the first page were repeatedly logged.

Comment: I've made a slight edit (requiring peer review, however) to your code to what worked for me - I had to make a slight adjustment after the fix. Thanks!